# Passing data in hash table to a listbox in C# using "for loop"

Tags: c#

I have been following this [C# tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s7p7.html) and found out that, it only describes to pass data in hash table to a list box using `foreach loop`.

I want to pass the data in my hash table using a `for loop`. Here's my code so far.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hashtable students = new Hashtable();

        students.Add("Peter", 67);
        students.Add("Brayan", 76);
        students.Add("Lincoln", 56);
        students.Add("Jack", 65);
        students.Add("Mahone", "no score");
        students.Add("Kevin", 64);

        for (int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(students[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

`Count method` in `for loop` works in `collections`. What's the right method for `for loop` when passing hash table data into a list box.

Comment: Don’t use the old `Hashtable` class, use the replacement `Dictionary` instead. The same is true for (almost) all classes from the `System.Collections` namespace. They should be considered deprecated.

Comment: @scylla : Is the input `no score` valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a `Dictionary` instead of a `HashTable`, you should also use a `foreach` to make things easier, then you can do:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> students = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    students.Add("Peter", 67);
    students.Add("Brayan", 76);
    students.Add("Lincoln", 56);
    students.Add("Jack", 65);
    students.Add("Mahone", 0);
    students.Add("Kevin", 64);

    foreach (var student in students)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(student.Value);
    }
}
```

**Note I replaced "no score" with 0 (thanks Viper)**

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Yes it will? `var` is a dynamic type. Explicit typing would actually be a `KeyValuePair`

Comment: Sorry, I thought you where using `HashTable` as OP did, Sure this will compile

Comment: @IlyaIvanov No problems :)

Comment: @mattytommo no it will not xD not because of `var` but the 'no score' is a string and your `Dictionary<string,int>` awaits an `int` .. but it was the code of the OP

Comment: Since everybody is telling me to use "for each loop" I guess I have no choice but to go ahead with "for each loop".

Comment: @mattytommo A better idea than to replace `"no score"` with zero would be to have the `Value` be of type `int?` and make that entry null.

Comment: @NominSim To be honest, I'd be inclined to agree. I don't want to complicate it for the OP for now though.

Comment: Thank you! mattytommo. It's neat and much easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a HashTable, you can't iterate through it using an index, you have to use the Keys collection on the Hashtable.

```
foreach(var key in student.Keys){
    listBox1.Items.Add(student[key].ToString());
}
```

Since the hash has been deprecated in favor of a dictionary, you should rework your solution to use it. However, if for some reason you can't (or don't want to), this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't access a hash table with an integer key (unless you used an `int` as your key in the first place). You need to use the keys you used when you constructed it (`string` in your case).

Luckily you can use the [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.keys.aspx) property of Hashtable and get the keys from there.

But the bigger question is, why do you want to do this with a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`? If your issue is that you want to have some kind of counter available, that's pretty easy to do just by setting a loop counter and incrementing it in your loop. Something like:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach (var thing in things)
{
    //do something with thing
    counter++;                 // this keeps track of how many you've processed.
}
```

Comment: Just to point out, the `Hashtable` can accept anything as a Key, so the OP certainly *can* access the Hashtable with something like `students[0]` (it will be null in this case as there is no entry with that Key *yet*)

Comment: "for loop" worked with everything including collections and arrays. So initially I thought it would work with hash tables too. Anyway I will move forward with "for each loop" for hash tables.

Comment: @scylla: Well it could work here to, if you loop over the `keys` collection and then use each key to access your `Hashtable`, but the question remains, why bother? You said you had a tutorial that used `foreach` so why did you want to use `for`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the `i` integer as a key in your hashtable because you have added a string. You have to pass the `string` value as we do with dictionaries, for sample:

```
students["Peter"] //return 67
```

Comment: even without the string ("no score") visual studio gives me the same error.

Comment: -1 This is mis-informative, you certainly can pass an integer as a key to the Hashtable, the problem is that he doesn't have anything with `int` keys, let alone ones corresponding to his for loop variable. When he passes the `int` values in the Hashtable indexing returns `null` as there are no entries corresponding to those keys.

Comment: Ok, I saw him cannot pass the `i` integer as a key based on his code, and in his code he have to pass the string as a key because he has added it , but ok :)

Answer (score 0):

You have your for loop going to students.count, not students.count-1.

The count is the total elements, and it's a zero based 'array' if you will - like others have said, use a for each statement instead, which is much neater too.

Answer (score 0):

starting index for the "students" is 0 as you have started the loop value from 0 so the last value should be students.Count-1 means your for loop will be

```
 for (int i = 0; i < students.Count-1; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(students[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hashtable student = new Hashtable();

    student.Add("Peter", 67);
    student.Add("Brayan", 76);
    student.Add("Lincoln", 56);
    student.Add("Jack", 65);
    student.Add("Mahone", "no score");
    student.Add("Kevin", 64);

    ICollection key = student.Keys;
    foreach (string k in key)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("Student: " + k + ", Score: " + student[k]);
    }
}
```